# Перехват аудио потока C++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, аудио

Проще говоря я хочу сделать эквалайзер на C++, но возникает вопрос: как перехватить любые звуки в системе?

С остальными этапами вывода на экран справлюсь, но прошу навести на выбор библиотеки(OpenAL, Phonon...?) и подходящего функционала.

Заранее спасибо за помощь )

Comment: А разве эквалайзер перехватывает звуки? Я думал, это системная функциональность...

Comment: Смотрите в сторону JACK — это и звуковой сервер, и куча библиотек по работе со звуком.

Comment: В пульсаудио есть эквалайзер. Надо только написать управляшку для него. И кстати каждое приложение управляется отдельно

Answer (score -1):

> я хочу сделать эквалайзер на C++

На мой взгляд (но это только моё мнение) С++ - не самый подходящий вариант для высоконагруженных приложений. Есть, однако, стандартный путь для разработки приложений для мультимедиа. Это  технология "GStreamer".

> GStreamer — мощный фреймворк для построения мультимедийных приложений,
>   который перенял идеи «video pipeline» от Oregon Graduate Institude, а
>   так же что-то взял из DirectShow. Данный фреймворк позволяет создавать
>   приложения различных уровней сложности, начиная от простого
>   консольного плеера (можно воспроизвести какой-нибудь файл прям из
>   терминала без написания какого-либо кода), заканчивая полноценными
>   аудио/видео плеерами, мультимедийными редакторами и прочими
>   приложениями.

https://habr.com/ru/post/178813/